# Focus on EditText in a Popup Window goes the activity to sleep

Tags: android, android-edittext, popupwindow

I place an `EditText` on a `PopupWindow` in my android project. When set `PopupWindow.setFocusable` to the false, the soft keyboard will not be show. And when set `PopupWindow.setFocusable` to the true, the `EditText` is focused and activity go to sleep!
Other item on the pop up window works, but back button on the phone and clicking outside the pop up does not close it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just set `setBackgroundDrawable` of `PopupWindow`. Everything seems be OK! I'm in consternation!!

Comment: What happened, is my answer was unhelpful?

Comment: Your answer direct me to the correct answer. **Thanks Ali** ( @AliImran ).

Answer (score 10):

Some code from my project may help

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        PopupWindow  share_popup = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_dropdown, null, false), 162, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        share_popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        share_popup.setTouchable(true);
        share_popup.setFocusable(true);
        Drawable image_saved = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dummy_bg);
        share_popup.setBackgroundDrawable(image_saved);
```

where this `R.drawable.dummy_bg` is a transparent image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Setting the `setBackgroundDrawable` solve my problem! I'm in consternation!!

Comment: Thak you. `new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_dropdown, null, false), 162, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);` Last `boolean` value `true` solves my problem.