# how to open combobox on type # in textarea in android 2.2

Tags: android, textchanged

I am working with android 2.2. i want following functionality how can i achieve this.

I have one textarea and I am writing text in that but when I type # it will open combobox to select value from combo box.

like

[image]

can anyone idea about this how can i perform this?

Comment: Use custom popup to implement such functionality.

Comment: @Ali Imran if you have any general example please give me link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html) for the custom design of PopupWindow.  android.widget.PopupWindow can be used to display an arbitrary view. The popup windows is a floating container that appears on top of the current activity. Also here is link for some [popWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899062/focus-on-edittext-in-a-popup-window-goes-the-activity-to-sleep/13899205#13899205)  usage

Answer (score 0):

Please check here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html, i think you want this:

[image: Are you searching for this?]

Anyhow if you want to customize it, you can do it. Thanks